# Add column break and space to using paragraph using styles

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, indesign-scripting, character-styles, xml

I'm going to design a fairly large festival programme and wish to make use of XML to ease the process.

But I need to be able to make column break after each entry, and also add spacing after certain XML tags.

I know how to make the XML tags connect to specific styles. But there seems to be no option other than *Search and Find* as to adding invisible characters.

I used the method of search and replace styles last year and the big drawback is that once you have done it, there is no going back – if you were to find out you did a mistake. Which is why I want to make use of XML to be able to make alterations to the structure afterwards.

Has anyone got any experience in this matter?

Comment: Also - it would be gret to be able to add labels to specific elements? Is that possible?

Comment: You can use regular expressions (GREP) in find/replace. Would that help you?

Comment: also if you save your work under a different name before you do your destructive search/replace, you will be able to "go back" if you discover you made a mistake.

Comment: That's the method I've been using so far. But I was hoping to find a way for the authors to correct spelling and grammar mistake and so forth using the xml file instead of me doing the tedious work in indesign.

Comment: Are grep styles useful here?

Answer (score 1):

> But I need to be able to make column break after each entry, and also add spacing after certain XML tags.

"Column Break" can be set in the Keep Options, and Space After in the Indents and Spacing section of the paragraph styles assigned to these tags.

Comment: But it is not possible to add an line-break after the first as such though, right? The "line break" needs to be part of the xml-doc in the first place as far as I can tell.
Maybe if I make the stucture as an template, and add the breaks and labels I want for an entry? I gonna try this out.

Comment: Problem is - what if certain tags are empty. The labels would still be represented. Hmm. Probably needs some scripting skills.

Comment: @Jakob You can choose when you import the XML whether or not to include empty tags.